# docker container unable to create directory in volume

Tags: docker, permissions, docker-volume

I installed docker on a Raspberry Pi.
I created the docker group and added my current user (pi) in the new group so I don't have to `sudo`my docker commands

A volume I want to use is created `docker volume create appdemaon_config` Created in `/var/lib/docker/volumes/appdaemon_config/_data` (root:root perms created by default)

Then when I start the container like so

```
docker run --rm --name=appdaemon -v appdaemon_config:/conf -p 5050:5050\ 
 -e HA_URL="http://192.168.1.105:8123"\
 -e ASH_URL="http://$HOSTNAME:5050" 76d1dca80fdaD`
```

(I also tried docker run with sudo, same result)

The script executed in the container is supposed to create 2 directories in the conf dir (which is the mounted volume) but it throws a permission error.

I'm not even allowed to `ls`the volume with my pi user, I have to sudo.

What am I missing about the perms or perms execution of a docker container ?

Comment: try entering the image with `docker exec` and manually create folders

Comment: I did and it works but I want the image to be portable and easy to use for other people.
changing the user:group of /var/lib/docker/volumes/ could be an option too but it's not a good practice I guess.

Comment: if it works when you enter the image, then it is probably your application's fault. Do you run the application as root or not? Your container is working just fine.

Comment: there is no USER defined in the Dockerfile when I build the image. As I understood it means root user is used by default. I run the dokcer image with pi user, which is in the docker group.

Comment: user in the host is not important. Your image is running as root but that does not mean that your application is too. For instance, there could be an entrypoint that does "su - <user> -c 'command'". Check with a ps inside the container who owns your applications' process

Comment: `root        25 10.0  2.6 160008 24812 ?        Sl   16:14   0:07 /usr/local/bin/python3.6 /usr/local/bin/appdaemon -c /conf`

Root is the owner.
I'm going to double check the entrypoint

Comment: What's the exact error? Are you sure you are trying to write in an existing folder?

Comment: Yes because other files are correctly moved to the volume. The script which is ran in the container move config files from a template dir to the volume then launch the dameon. The demon checks if config files are present, starts and then creates directories (that's where it fails) which will contain compressed js/css/html. I added the "compressed" directories in my conf template dir. Everything works fine now. It's an obvious solution but I hoped to know why it failed. Thank you for your help.